# Write to CSV - Multiple blank rows created

Tags: python, csv, cursor, blank-line

I'm very new at Python and I trying to insert data from SQL to a CSV.
I have the following code:

```
sql = cursor.execute("SELECT field_a, field_b, field_c FROM TableA LIMIT 500")
    result=cursor.fetchall()
    fp = open('dataset.csv', 'w')
    myFile = csv.writer(fp)
    myFile.writerows(result)
    fp.close()
```

But when I see the CSV created I have multiple blank lines. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the code `result` is never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.7:

```
fp = open('dataset.csv', 'wb')
```

Python 3.x:

```
fp = open('dataset.csv', 'w', newline='')
```